# How to get data from Remote Database for LoginPage fro validation? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, bootstrap-4

I have created a login page in bootstrap in ASP.NET MVC and now I want to add remote database connection to access data for validation I have database IP Address Username and password but I can't connect it how I will going to do that?

Is there anyone who can share complete code of login page demo with connection with remote database which can access data for validation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this examples:

https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/how-to-create-simple-login-form-using.html

https://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/08/how-to-create-login-pageform-and-check.html

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-Form-with-Database-connection-example-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx